# File cloud-sql-proxy.service: Invalid argument - Google cloud

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, cloud-sql-proxy

While I am trying to create an ephemeral Dataproc cluster along with loading data from a MySQL instance, I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to enable unit: File cloud-sql-proxy.service: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Can you share your cluster create command config?